# No Llama de sucess de AJAX a función,

Tags: javascript

```
function waitPreloadPage()
{
$.ajax({
   type: "get",
   url:"srvBuscarAsientoBlo",
   async: true,
   cache: false,
    data:{
             parIdViaje: $('input[name=txtViaje]').val()                 
               },
              success: function(resp){
               $.each(resp, function(indice,estado){

               $('input[name=inputTotal]').val(String(addZeroes(estado.total)));
                                      });

                        }     
                });

          function addZeroes( num ) {
           return num;
             }
 }
```

Comment: Si no hace el success, colocale tambien el calback de error osea asi como el success pero error y alli adentro colocas un console.log a ver que esta pasando muy seguramente te esta dando un error y por eso no entra en el success

Comment: `srvBuscarAsientoBlo` tiene algún tipo de extensión?

Comment: No tiene una extensión, llama directamente a un servlet